# Drupal Database 4 byte UTF-8 support

Tags: mysql, utf-8, drupal-7

I have recently updated my Drupal site to 7.5 but now I run the database update script and this is causing problems with changes to panels.

I get the following message when running the update script:

The autorotate image effect requires the exif extension to be enabled.

4 byte UTF-8 for mysql is disabled

I do not have drush.

Is there a way to run the database update script without converting the database to UTF-8 ?

Comment: what about running {your_domain}/update.php in your server. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

If its just the notice on the "Status Report" page, you can ignore it. It's just a notification that the feature is available (as of 7.50). You can get the notice to go away by amending your settings.php database connection by adding:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'databasename',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
);
```

**NOTE:** If you modify your database to utf8mb4, you will not be able to use it in a plain utf8 database.

See more info here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/utf8mb4_convert